# Displaying a large image in an ImmediateLayer

Tags: playn

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z95vw.jpg

EDIT - In an attempt to demonstrate this issue better, it appears that a large image in an Immediate layer is being clipped to the size of the ImmediateLayer.

In the sample image, there's two ImmediateLayers. The left hand size displays an image that's bigger than the size of the ImmediateLayer and appears clipped when rotated *or* translated. On the right hand side a low res version of the image is scaled up and displayed in the same position. Unclipped.

In the background the original hires version of the image is shown, showing that its loaded in its entirety, and only being clipped when shown in the ImmediateLayer.

So, not a rotation issue, but an issue of can an image be displayed and translated in an ImmediateLayer without being clipped?

ORIGINAL -

In PlayN, I'm trying to rotate an image when rendering to a clipped ImmediateLayer. I can rotate an image by setting the surface's rotation at render time, but this causes an image to be clipped then rotated. So, a star image would have its points clipped before its rotated into place.

Is this rotation code correct and the clipping a bug?

```
surface.save();

surface.rotate(rotation);

surface.drawImage(star, 0, 0);
surface.restore();
```

Bit of background, the reason for using an ImmediateLayer is to have 2 player split-screen view, side-by-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@samskivert - running your example code and comparing it to your screenshot I noticed I had completely different results - I had no clipping at all.

Moving my project's playn dependency from 1.2 to 1.3.1 and therefore to Lwjgl resolved the issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mljoj.jpg

Exact same code, wrong dependency. Thanks for your help getting to the bottom of the issue, and thanks for piling so much good work into playn!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

You're clearly doing something wrong. I added an example of drawing an image through a rotation and translation trasform into a clipped ImmediateLayer and it works just fine. Check out [this example](https://github.com/threerings/playn/blob/master/tests/core/src/main/java/playn/tests/core/ImmediateTest.java) and hopefully it will illuminate what you're doing wrong.

[image: Example of rotated and translated image drawing into clipped layer]

ORIGINAL:

Can you post a screenshot demonstrating the error?

No clipping takes place other than to the bounds of the ImmediateLayer that defines the clipping region (and you should definitely *not* rotate the ImmediateLayer itself).

So it should not matter whether you rotate the Surface transform and then draw your image. If parts of the rotated image fall outside the bounds of the ImmediateLayer, those parts will be clipped. But everything that's inside the bounds of the immediate layer will be drawn as normal.

Comment: Original question updated to include screenshot and further clarification.